# Android not asking permissions / recording not working

Tags: android, audio, audiorecord

I am developing an app that listens to the phone's microphone. On 2 out of 4 devices available to me it works very well and those ask permission to record audio during install. Other 2 don't not ask and also do not work, at all. The code where I initialize AudioRecord instance does not return me any error messages at any point. Therefore, I think that those 2 devices that don't work just won't ask for permission and also won't give one.

My initialization code:

```
protected void init() {
    bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(INPUT_SAMPLE_RATE,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

    arraySize = bufferSize;
    try {
        input = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                INPUT_SAMPLE_RATE,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                bufferSize * 10
        );
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.e("E_RECORDER", "Recorder.init() IllegalArgumentException");
    }

    input.setPositionNotificationPeriod(arraySize);

    input.setRecordPositionUpdateListener(new AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMarkerReached(AudioRecord recorder) {
        }   

        @Override
        public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioRecord recorder) {
            int samplesRead = input.read(data, 0, arraySize);
            process(data);
        }
    });
    input.startRecording();
}
```

Edit:

Actually there is some log about it too:

```
E/AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for record source 1
E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
E/AudioRecord-Java: [ android.media.AudioRecord ] Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
```

Comment: What version of Android is on the ones that don't work? 6.0 uses the new runtime permissions, where your code has to ask permission each time it needs to do something like using the mic.

Comment: I am targeting devices as low as APK 15. And the ones that do not ask permissions are actually a bit cheaper and older phones. HTC One V (APK 15) and some other Motorola. So it cannot be runtime permissions.